# Snowflake How to resume root task after it gets suspended?

Tags: sql, triggers, task, scheduled-tasks, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have the following root and child task. Everything works as intended but how can I automatically have `TSK_ROOT` resume after it gets suspended? Do I have to make another task that checks if `TSK_ROOT` is suspended? Doesn't that defeat the purpose of a root task?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TASK TSK_ROOT
    WAREHOUSE  = MYWH
    SCHEDULE = '5 MINUTE'
WHEN
    SYSTEM$STREAM_HAS_DATA('<stream_name>')
AS 
    ALTER TASK TSK_ROOT SUSPEND;
 
CREATE OR REPLACE TASK TKS_ONE
    WAREHOUSE = MYWH
    AFTER TSK_ROOT
AS
     ....
```

Comment: Why is the task suspending itself in this code?

Comment: `AFTER TSK_ROOT` is the condition for the child tasks I have. The child task will run after `TSK_ROOT` is suspended.

Answer (score 0):

What I understand from the comments:

- `TKS_ONE` runs after a run of `TSK_ROOT`.
- Question assumes that `TKS_ONE` only runs after `TSK_ROOT` is suspended, hence `TSK_ROOT` incorporates code to suspend itself.
- That's not necessarily true. `TSK_ROOT` could run anything, `select 1 x` for example, and `TKS_ONE` would run regardless.

So to avoid suspending `TSK_ROOT`, just don't suspend it from within `TSK_ROOT`.

Check this example:

- https://github.com/fhoffa/snowflake_snippets/blob/main/stream_and_tasks/minimal.sql

Comment: So the `AFTER` condition is not dependent on the Root task being suspended? From reading the documentation, "Specifies the predecessor task for the current task. When a run of the predecessor task finishes successfully, it triggers this task (after a brief lag)."

Comment: Exactly. When `SELECT 1` finishes, the second task will be triggered. There's no need to `suspend` to `finish`

Answer (score 0):

The Suspend / resume  should be used to turn on(resume) or off(suspend) for maintenance of code not as an operational function.

maybe try something like

> SCHEDULE = 'USING CRON */5 9 * * * PST8PDT'

since you have the
SYSTEM$STREAM_HAS_DATA('<stream_name>') in your when clause it will not resume your warehouse / consume credits if it the stream is empty.

If this is a theoretical and not an operational question:

For any task chain with a schedule and following tasks in sequence like so

> Root(scheduled)--task1( after root) --task2( after task1) --task3
> (after task2)

'suspend' must be applied from the left and 'resume' from the right
it is possible for the sequence to be like

```
resumed -- suspended -- resumed -- suspended
```

but in practice it should always look like one of these

```
resumed   -- resumed   -- resumed   -- resumed 
suspended -- resumed   -- resumed   -- resumed 
suspended -- suspended -- resumed   -- resumed 
suspended -- suspended -- suspended -- resumed 
suspended -- suspended -- suspended -- suspended
```

so in this case  if your operant goal is to run task1 once.

have root do a do nothing statement like select current_date;

Do what you must with task1
and then have
task2 'alter task root suspend;'